# File name beginning with - (dash)

Tags: shell, shell-script, quoting, filenames

I have file called `-l` in my directory

now I tried to do

```
for i in *; do stat -c "%s %n" "$i"; done
```

it lists all files with sizes but in the middle of the output there is something like

```
395 koko.pub
stat: invalid option -- 'l'
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
2995974 list.txt
```

so it can not process `-l` as normal filename, how do I get desired behavior from `stat`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `./` before filename:

```
for i in *; do stat -c "%s %n" "./$i"; done
```

Or use `--` to indicate the end of options for `stat`:

```
for i in *; do stat -c "%s %n" -- "$i"; done
```

Though that one will still fail for a file called `-` (will report information for the file open on stdin instead of the `-` file in the current directory).

Comment: Using `for i in ./*` should also work

Answer (score 7):

Add `--` to mark the end of the options to `stat`:

```
for i in *; do stat -c "%s %n" -- "$i"; done
```

Answer (score -2):

Even simpler, rename the file to -_I or simply I without the dash. Simply as a matter of purient curosity WHY did you place a dash in front of the file in the first pplac?